# Are there any browser automation tools that support video and audio recording?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, browser-automation, tools

I'm searching for a browser automation tool that can record video and audio.

Selenium, Cypress, and Playwright do not support audio recording. Puppeteer maybe with [puppeteer-stream](https://github.com/Flam3rboy/puppeteer-stream) but I'm not sure how stable and production ready is this, never tried it.

Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply record the screen using FFMPEG

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s wxga -r 25 -i :0.0 -qscale 0 recording.mpg
```

https://andreafortuna.org/2019/09/20/how-to-record-screen-on-linux-from-command-line/

Answer (score -1):

I had completed this problem via Selenium and a Python solution, using this information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536303/detect-audio-with-selenium-webdriver-and-python